# Rebinding CameraX UseCases

Tags: android, android-camerax

I am trying to stop/pause the camera `PreviewView` during image processing/detection using `Firebase MLKit`. To pause the preview I call

```
cameraProvider.unbind(previewUseCase)
```

That stops the preview on the last frame but now I dont know how to restart it. I tried just binding the preview again like this

```
cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview)
```

But that causes the `PreviewView` to just show white like its gone and cant get it back ntil  restart the app.

The same thing happens when I call `unbindAll()`

So my question is how do I pause the preview view and then restart it again at a later point?

this is my code

```
fun setupCamera(windowManager: WindowManager, previewView: PreviewView){

    _cameraProvider = _cameraProviderFuture.get()

    _preview = Preview.Builder()
        .setTargetRotation(windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation)
        .build()

    _preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.previewSurfaceProvider)

    _cameraSelector = CameraSelector.Builder()
        .requireLensFacing(_requiredCameraLens)
        .build()

    _imageAnalyzer = ImageAnalysis.Builder()
        .setTargetResolution(Size(_imageWidth, _imageHeight))
        .setBackpressureStrategy(_imageBackpressureStrategy)
        .build()

    _imageAnalyzer.setAnalyzer(_imageExecutor,_analyzer)

    startPreview()

    _cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(_lifecycleOwner, _cameraSelector, _imageAnalyzer)
}

// Called after image processing has finished
fun startPreview(){
    _cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(_lifecycleOwner, _cameraSelector, _preview)
}

// Called when object is detected in an image
fun stopPreview(){
    _cameraProvider.unbind(_preview)
}
```

Comment: Which version of CameraX that you use?

Comment: @harrytmthy `1.0.0-alpha10` is the version I am using. I believe its the most recent version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test my solution in Kotlin but it's working fine in Java. Indeed if you just call cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(lifecycleOwner, cameraSelector, preview) it will not really rebind your preview. In fact you have to recreate a preview and to reset the surface provider. For instance in Java when I want to rebind my preview I use:

```
public void rebindPreview(){
    Preview preview = new Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetName("Preview")
            .build();
    preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.getPreviewSurfaceProvider());
    Camera camera = cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(this, cameraSelector, preview, imageCapture);
}
```

I assume that for Kotlin you can do something like this:

```
fun rebindPreview(){
    _preview = Preview.Builder()
            .setTargetRotation(windowManager.defaultDisplay.rotation)
            .setTargetName("Preview")
            .build()
    _preview.setSurfaceProvider(previewView.previewSurfaceProvider)
    _cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(_lifecycleOwner, _cameraSelector, _preview)
}
```

Comment: That seems to reset everything however I get a white screen for about a second when everything rebinds. is there a way to prevent that?

Comment: Of course there is some time needed to rebind. You can't really prevent that. You could just not unbind to continue to have your previewView working. But if you absolutely need to unbind and then to rebind I would suggest you to display the taken image during the time you are processing in order to avoid this white screen or maybe to display a loading effect like a progress bar or a shimmer effect.

Comment: @PaulSouteyrat is right. You can't currently rebind a use case you called `unbind` on. However, why do you need to pause then resume preview while running your analysis? Is it because it takes too long?

Comment: @HusaynHakeem My use case was I wanted to do an animation with the frame that something was found in after analysis so I wanted to "pause" the view with its current frame

Answer (score 0):

In adittion to paul answer. if you are using Android composable you have to do the changes inside Android view in the updated method

```
AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),

        factory = { context ->
            val previewView = PreviewView(context)
            //no changes here, it only initialized once
            previewView
        },
        update = {
            bindCamera..()
        }
)
```